# Android GoogleBox, OneDrive, DropBox pick a file intent

Tags: android, android-intent

In the application I'm writing a user should be able to pick a text file from either of: GoogleBox, OneDrive, DropBox. After picking a file, application reads its content and parses.

I'm pretty sure there must be an intent for each of the providers but I can't find any info.
Can anyone suggest any resources on this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting the intents for each Cloud Storage provider, you can always use the Cloud Rail Single Interface: http://docs.cloudrail.com/docs/getting-started.

It is free to use, and there is Android support.

Basically, it allows you to use the same functions and the same inputs for all OneDrive and Dropbox. It also means that you can change what Cloud Storage provider is being used by chaning one line of code. So this does also mean that you can have whichever one is used being defined by your user's choice.

You can check it out at http://docs.cloudrail.com/docs/getting-started. If you do have any comments, please feel free to email me personally at luke@cloudrail.com